# Error al subir imagen a servidor NodeJs con multer

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, multer

estoy realizando un aplicacion con react y nodeJs , y estoy haciendo un formulario de creacion de noticias y el mismo tiene una imagen.
de esta manera obtengo la imagen usando react dropzone:

```
export function BoxImage(props:any) {
 let {postcontent , setcontent}:any = props;
 let [imagen , setimage]:any = useState({
 });
 let {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({
   accept:"image/*",
   multiple:false,
   onDropAccepted:(acceptedFiles)=>{
     console.log(acceptedFiles[0]);
      setimage({
        preview: URL.createObjectURL(acceptedFiles[0])
        })
        setcontent({
          ...postcontent,
          image: SetImage(acceptedFiles[0])
        })

  },
  
 });
```

Luego formateo la imagen:

```
export function SetImage(image:File){
    const formdata = new FormData()  
    console.log("image: ", image);
    formdata.append('image', image)
    console.log(formdata);
   return formdata;
}
```

Una vez que obtengo la imagen la coloco en un objeto que contiene todas las podriedades del formulario y en la propiedad image coloco lo que retorna mi funcion setimage (la imagen seteada)

Por ultimo  envio los datos al servidor:

```
async function  SubmitPost(NewsForm:NewsType){
try{
 let send = await AddPost(NewsForm);
 console.log(send);
}catch(err){
console.log(err)
}

}
```

Ahora en mi servidor creo el midleware de multer:

```
const multer = require('multer')
const path = require('path');
const diskstorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: path.join(__dirname, '../images') ,
     filename: (req, file, cb) => {
     cb(null, Date.now() + '-imageprueba-' + file.originalname)
      }
    })
     const fileUpload = multer({
        storage: diskstorage
    }).single('image')


module.exports = fileUpload;
```

Creo la ruta y el controlador e importo el modulo de multer:

```
router.post('/api/posts', authmiddleware.auth, fileUpload, controllerpost.createPost)

exports.createPost =(req, res, next)=>{
let {title,subtitle, body, UserId} = req.body

console.log(
   {"title": title,
    "subtitle" :subtitle,
    "image":req.file, ==> deberia recibir la imagen
    "UserId":UserId,
    "Body": body
   }
)

}
```

en req.file deberia tener la imagen pero no la obtengo, no se si es un problema al obtener el nombre de la imagen ya que viene en la propiedad imagen del objeto y yo solo coloque:

```
  const fileUpload = multer({
        storage: diskstorage
    }).single('image') ==> tal vez puede ser este el problema
```

Comment: ¿Agregaste en el código `html` del form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: en el input de la imagen dices? porque no tengo una etiqueta form son diversos input , uno para cada propiedad del objeto enviado al servidor. Ejemplo un input para image, otro para title ,etc

Comment: ¿Pero esos inputs no están dentro de un form?

Comment: no los coloque dentro de un form

Comment: ¿pero y entonces a donde estás enviando la información? ¿Con qué método? [Multer](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html) requiere el campo `enctype`. Ya ahí tienes varios errores que parten desde que no los definiste dentro de un form hasta que te faltan atributos. No adjuntas esa parte del código.

Comment: estoy obteniendo los datos de los inputs y los coloco dentro de un estado que es un objeto con todas las propiedades del formulario . Una vez que el usuario hace submit , obtengo el estado con todas sus propiedades , la image se setea y se lo envia al servidor .

Comment: Sube el formulario para ver como pasas la info al useState de la imagen